# Processes surviving Windows VM reboots?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012, vmware-esxi

*Summary:* A <strike>long-running</strike> virtual Windows Server 2012 system this weekend became very slow; from remote we did `Restart-Computer -ComputerName xyzzy -Force`, which succeeded by all accounts; except that *some processes look like they have survived at least 10 reboots*.

And as this is the first time I see this in 20+ years of using Windows, I'd *really* like to know what happened.

---

Here is a chronological story:

- This system has been rebooted at least 10 times between August 8, 2014 and January 19, 2015.  The last reboot was on January 16.
- The VM, which is running on VMware ESXi 5.5.0, was barely reachable anymore through web-based UIs and Remote Desktop: its behavior suggested that some process or processes were taking up the CPU.
- We decided to reboot the server from another Windows system, using Powershell: `Restart-Computer -ComputerName xyzzy`.
- This took quite a while and then returned an error indicating that users were still logged in.
- Fair enough, let's apply force: `Restart-Computer -ComputerName xyzzy -Force`.
- This took quite a while and then returned.
- In the meantime I had a `ping -t xyzzy` running, to check that the network interface would go down, to check that the reboot really occurred.  It did: for about a minute or two that repeatedly gave me `Request timed out.` and then the ping replies resumed.
- Then I successfully connected with Remote Desktop.  This showed a dialog saying that the system shut down unexpectedly, and asked me to fill in the reason.

  - This was a bit unexpected, but may be standard after a remote `Restart-Computer`.
- To find out the reason for that dialog I checked the event viewer, and could find nothing amiss.  And I did observe all kinds of Kernel-Boot and lots related events, reporting uptimes of 20 seconds and 79 seconds.
- *(nothing for a while)*
- Then we observed that the system was becoming slow again, and I connected with Remote Desktop and had a look with Process Explorer.  That resulted in the following:

  [image: Process Explorer screenshot]

  The right-most column, with dates of 1/19 (January 19th, 2015) and 8/14 (August 14th, 2014), is the 'Start Time' column of Process Explorer, and I sorted on that column.
- <strike>That August 2014 sounds like a realistic date of when we last rebooted this system</strike> This same date-time was also observed by another process which manages the shown java.exe processes: it reported processes started 158 days ago.  And according to Process Explorer, these were some of the processes that were eating up CPU and making the system slow.  Finally, the per-process log files for the java.exe processes 3248, 4568, and 4236 give no indication whatsoever that these processes were ever stopped: they have log messages from both August 14th, 2014, and from the first minutes after the reboot.

So I can come to only one conclusion: *the system has rebooted for about 90%,* including the network stack and something that writes Kernel-Boot events, *but 10 processes survived the reboot.*

**So, what could reasonably have caused this?**

Was there perhaps a weird mixup of an old August 2014 VMware image/snapshot, and a fresh boot?  Note that VMware has no snapshot for this system.

---

Note that since the system was becoming unusable again, I did a `Restart-Computer -Force` locally, causing a reboot, and this time there were no processes left over.  So everything looks fine now, but I don't have the live system anymore: I can only do forensics.